# How to add animation?

Tags: javascript, fadeout

How will I add fadeout animation in this javascript code?

```
document.getElementById("mt-alerts").style.display="block";
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("mt-alerts").style.display="none";
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, display: none cannot be animated due to the element being physically removed from the DOM. You might try using opacity instead. Check out this blog: https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using display, you need to start with opacity for this.

The idea is simply decrease the opacity of your element until it reaches the 0, then set its display as none. To fade in you can repeat the idea in reverse.

```js
function js_fadeOut(targetID, intervalMs, fadeWeight) {

    var fadeTarget = document.getElementById(targetID);
    
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
        if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
        }
        if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity -= fadeWeight;
        } else {
            fadeTarget.style.display = "none";
            clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        }
    }, intervalMs*fadeWeight);
}
```

```html
<div id='target' style='padding:8px; background:lightblue;' onclick='js_fadeOut("target", 200, 0.1)'>Click to fadeOut</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use this as my reference

Answer (score 0):

You should make classses for every animations, and the JS should change only the classes of the items.
You can with this method, make your own animatsions.

```js
const alertMsg = document.getElementById("mt-alerts");
const hide = document.getElementById("hide");
const red = document.getElementById("red");

hide.addEventListener("click", ()=> alertMsg.classList.toggle("hidden"));
red.addEventListener("click", ()=> alertMsg.classList.toggle("red"));
```

```css
#mt-alerts {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  color: black;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0!important;
}

.red {
  color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="mt-alerts">My Alert</div>
<button id="hide">Hide/show</button>
<button id="red">Make it red</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use this as my reference.